# Find and replace with Increment in excel macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to replace one value in excel formula in all sheet but the value get incremented with 1 in each sheet

I had try these macro but it changes with same value

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()
'PURPOSE: Find & Replace text/values throughout entire workbook

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant
Dim p As Integer
Dim q As Integer
p = 3
q = p + 1
fnd = "$3"
rplc = "$" & q

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next sht
p=q
End Sub
```

Comment: please post also some sample data, and explain what exactly "it changes with same value" means.

Comment: INDIRECT("'[122016.xlsm]"&$A4&"'!E$3") in sheet 1                                           want to change to                                        INDIRECT("'[122016.xlsm]"&$A4&"'!E$4")  in sheet 2  INDIRECT("'[122016.xlsm]"&$A4&"'!E$5")  in sheet 3 INDIRECT("'[122016.xlsm]"&$A4&"'!E$6")  in sheet 4  and so on till 400 Sheets

Comment: It may work better if you edit your question to include a clearer example of the data rather than putting it in a comment. Are you expecting this value to be in different places on each worksheet? Are you expecting it to appear multiple times on the sheet?

Comment: it apper multiple times in sheet and want on same place of existing formula

Comment: Inside your `For` loop, but before your `sht.Cells.Replace`, you need to add `q = q + 1` and `rplc = "$" & q`.